# Can I instal windows 8.1pro to my acer swift 3 sf314-42?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a licension on windows 8.1 pro, but haven`t it for windows 10. I want to instal windows 8.1 pro and then upgrade it to windows 10.
Can I instal windows 8.1 pro on my laptop Acer Swift 3 SF314-42-R1J0 (NX.HULEU.00P) , if yes, how can I do that? And can I than upgrade it to windows 10?

Comment: Why don’t you just install Windows 10?  Windows 10 will accept a Windows 8 license, that’s been the case, for nearly 5 years.  I have almost 5 answers that explicitly explain the digital entitlement and free upgrade to Windows 10.  However, technically that program expired 2 and half years ago, so if you want Windows 10 you should purchase a license

Comment: If you do a simple web search, you will find that there are still plenty of ways to (legally) upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 10 without paying for additional licensing.  Since this is SuperUser.. and this is sort of a grey area.. nobody here is likely going to help you do this.  You will either need to figure it out on your own or purchase a fresh license.

Comment: Why would you need to install Windows 8.1? The web page for your laptop explicitly states the product comes with Windows 10 Home preinstalled, which should be OEM activated, so why would you want to downgrade to Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

on My swift its going USER
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
Microsoft Corporation
Standalone Workstation
Multiprocessor Free
RAI
2016-11-23, 23:18:05
2021-04-16, 01:44:07
Acer
Swift SF314-51